# Difference between read only and disabled in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying a jQuery datepicker for a textbox.When i used `readonly` for that textbox the `datepicker` is coming.But when i used `disabled` the datepicker is not coming.

Readonly means it can not open `jQuery datepicker`.What is the reason for this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be that way? `readonly` means the date is not editable, but the UI control still works. But `disabled`... well it's disabled from any user interaction.

Comment: I think with readonly you can still give focus to the field, while with disabled you can't even do that.